# How to programmatic-ally connect iPhone 4s to any other smart phones via Bluetooth LE?

Tags: android, ios

I am using a sample code to connect iPhone 4S to an Android device via bluetooth LE. But the iPhone cannot discover it. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: Are you talking iOS 5.x here? In that OS version, the iOS device can only be the central device, not the peripheral. Is the Android device acting as a peripheral or a central device?

Comment: No i have ios 6 installed in my iphone 4s and the another android device is motorola razor...how to know a device is central or peripheral??can u please tell me.

Comment: I highly recommend watching the WWDC 2012 session 703 "Core Bluetooth 101" if you don't know what central and peripheral devices are, because you need to understand those concepts before you get too far into Bluetooth LE. Also, it wouldn't hurt to show the code that you're using on the iPhone to discover LE devices.

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.3 does not support Advertising yet, you have to make it the central device and iOS the peripheral.